# Common encoding for Chinese and Latin character in Python

Tags: python, flask, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

We have a REST API which accepts payload containing Chinese characters (for eg: 赵狄) and Latin characters (for eg: Ä). Since its a generic REST API, we want to decode the payload once using some universal decoder.
Issues faced: While using UTF-8 decoder, Latin characters gives an error, and while using latin-1 decoder, Chinese characters get decoded as '?'.

REST API service is developed using Flask, and we are using following piece of code for decoding

```
requestPayload = request.data.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: The payload itself should identify which encoding it is using, either in the content or the protocol metadata.

Comment: @MarkRansom are you suggesting that client should add some content header while making HTTP request, and how would then the code look like for decoding using it?

Comment: also, not sure if the client calling these REST API would be able to send this information in header (since client is a legacy system with very little configurable parts)

Comment: I'm not fully versed on the details of the protocol, when I need to worry about it I try to use a library that just does the right thing.  Although I think if there are multiple ways to specify the encoding you might end up with a conflict where they don't match, the result being mojibake.